# calculate mean and variance with one iteration

Tags: python, iterator

I have an iterator of numbers, for example a file object:

```
f = open("datafile.dat")
```

now I want to compute:

```
mean = get_mean(f)
sigma = get_sigma(f, mean)
```

What is the best implementation? Suppose that the file is big and I would like to avoid to read it twice.

Comment: Do you want to avoid reading the file twice, or avoid iterating twice?

Comment: I don't think you are showing us the full code. You are passing a file to `get_mean()` where `fsum()` only accepts lists of numbers.

Comment: Why do you need to place a restriction on modifying the function? If you rearranged the formula for the variance, I think you can get something like sqrt(1/(n-1)*(sum(li**2 for li in l) + n*mm*sum(li for li in l) + n*mm)) where n is len(l). That is, if my math is correct. Then you can iterate once, calculating the sum terms in the above refactoring and the mean at the same time.

Comment: @Otto: you are right, I reformulated the question

Comment: @SilentGhost: > 1M lines

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to iterate once, you can write your sum function:

```
def mysum(l):
    s2 = 0
    s = 0
    for e in l:
        s += e
        s2 += e * e
    return (s, s2)
```

and use the result in your `sigma` function.

**Edit**: now you can calculate the variance like this: (s2 - (s*s) / N) / N

By taking account of @Adam Bowen's comment,
keep in mind that if we use mathematical *tricks* and transform the original formulas
we may degrade the results.

Comment: With this solution the mean is `s/n` and the variance is `s2/n - mean*mean` that is to say, the mean of the squares minus the square of the mean. However, you must be aware that calculating the variance this way may be inaccurate for large n because of the difference in scale between s2 and e*e during the accumulation. Unfortunately, this means that for large n the two-pass algorithm is much more accurate (and a better choice).

Comment: This answer is referenced in [PEP 450](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0450/) as being advice for a naive approach to variance calculation with poor stability and accuracy characteristics. See for comparison the variance functions in the proposed Python 3.4+ [`statistics`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/statistics.py) module.

Comment: @badp thanks, I wasn't aware of this. My answer demonstrates how to calculate mean and variance with one iteration, and it could be improved to handle floats and be more accurate. PEP 450 references my answer although the calculation is done with a different algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

I think Nick D has the correct answer.

Assuming you want to compute both mean and variance in one sweep of the file (and you don't really want two functions that have to be called one after the other), you can collect the sum of the values and of their squares and them use such sums (toghether with the number of read elements) to compute at the same time mean and variance.

There are some numerical stability issues, but the idea in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_formula_for_the_variance

is the basic ingredient you need. Some more details are at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance

where I suggest you to read the "Naïve algorithm".

Hope this helps,

Massimo

Answer (score 3):

Make a list from the iterable, or use [`itertools.tee()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee).

Comment: but wouldn't whole file has to be kept in memory? because get_sigma needs input from get_mean, in that case why not just load whole file in memory

Comment: `t1, t2 = tee(...)` isn't worth the shot if you want to consume whole `t1` first and whole `t2` later. In such case just use `list(seq)` and iterate over that

Answer (score 3):

You can compute both in one pass. See:

http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is much choice.

You will have to iterate your numbers twice in any case as the standard deviation will require the mean information on each value.

If you have enough memory, you can gain on the I/O access by loading your file in memory during the first iteration but that is about it IMO.

Comment: Untrue, the single pass algorithm for calculating standard deviation is widely published and available on-line.

Answer (score 1):

As I feel that there are good elements scattered in multiple answers, I would like to summarize:

- If your file is too big to conveniently fit in memory, and if you want a good precision in the variance, you do need to read the file twice (with one pass, the variance is the difference between two large numbers, which is not precise because of floating point limitations).  Note that your operating system is likely to provide some automatic speed-up for the second file reading, as it may still be in RAM during the second pass.
- If you do not care for the precision of the variance, you can simply iterate once over the file and calculate the quantities suggested by Nick D, with the details provided in the comment by Adam Bowen.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions

1. Make a list out of your iterator and loop it as many time as you wish. Drawback is everything will be in memory, so not suitable if your file is big. Simple use of itertools.tee also will not save you
2. There is no other solution , **unless** , you do not need to pass output of  get_mean to get_sigma, because in that case they can only be in series, but if you remove this restriction then you can run both functions in parallel using threads, and use itertools.tee to have two iterators from one

Answer (score 0):

You can use map reduce in an elegant fashion way

sample is the list you want to get its variance

sample = [a,b,c, ...]

```
mean = float(reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, sample)) / len(sample)

variance = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, map(lambda xi: (xi-mean)**2, sample))/ len(sample)
```

In a succinct line of code:

```
variance = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, map(lambda xi: (xi-(float(reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, sample)) / len(sample)))**2, sample))/ len(sample)
```

Comment: to get the mean you don't need all this: you can simply `sum(sample) / len(sample)` and similar for the variance. The big point here you're iterating two times on my *big* file. My question asked for *one iteration*

Comment: oops!- yes, you're right. But it's a good pretext to use lambda functions =)